# Check authentication state using stream not working in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I'm using `GoogleSignIn`.

On my splash screen, I'm using `StreamBuilder` to check whether the user is logged in or not, and based on that data I'm trying to show the Login Screen or Home Screen.

When I uninstall and reinstall the app it shows the Login Screen for the first time. And then after it always shows me the Home Screen even if I logged out from the app.

Below is my code for `Splash Screen`:

```dart
class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SplashScreenState createState() => _SplashScreenState();
}

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SizeConfig().init(context);
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<User> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          print(snapshot.hasData);
          return AnimatedSplashScreen(
            splashIconSize: SizeConfig.blockSizeVertical * 16,
            splashTransition: SplashTransition.fadeTransition,
            nextScreen: HomeScreen(),
            splash: kLogoImage,
            duration: 800,
          );
        } else {
          print(snapshot.hasData);
          return AnimatedSplashScreen(
            splashIconSize: SizeConfig.blockSizeVertical * 16,
            splashTransition: SplashTransition.fadeTransition,
            nextScreen: LoginScreen(),
            splash: kLogoImage,
            duration: 800,
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Below is my code for `Home Screen`:

```dart
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
  User firebaseUser;

  signOut() async {
    await googleSignIn.signOut();
    Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, MyRoutes.loginScreen);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Center(
            child: Text('Hello'),
          ),
          MaterialButton(
              child: Text('Log out'),
              color: Colors.red,
              onPressed: () {
                signOut();
              })
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could it be that GoogleSignIn is not the same as Firebase?

Try replacing `googleSignIn.signOut()` with `FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut()` on your `home screen`.

Comment: I'm glad your issue is fixed, but why are you using both [`google_sign_in`](https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in) and [`firebase_auth`](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth)?

Comment: I don't know what is the problem with `googleSignIn.signOut()` but replacing this with `FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut()` solves the issue. Maybe because `googleSignIn.signOut()` doesn't update the `authStateChanges()` stream. But in `FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut()` method's documentation says that FirebaseAuth 's `signOut` method updates the `authStateChanges()` stream. This might the reason of faliure.

Comment: I want `GoogleSignIn` in my app. But I also need other data such as `currentUser`, `profilePhoto` and all. That can be achieved using FirebaseAuth. So I'm using it.

Comment: Can I achieve the needs without using `FirebaseAuth`. If so then please guide me on that.

Comment: [You can](https://pub.dev/documentation/google_sign_in/latest/google_sign_in/GoogleSignInAccount/photoUrl.html). If you want to let your users sign in using their Google accounts only, use `google_sign_in` and get rid of `firebase_auth`. If you want to offer "sign in with google" as well as more sign in options (sign in with apple, sign in with facebook, traditional email/password, etc) use `firebase_auth` and get rid of `google_sign_in`.

Comment: FYI: if you plan to release an app on the iOS appstore and you implement "sign in with google", you must also implement sign in with apple as [per Apple's rules](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#sign-in-with-apple).

Comment: Ohh, that is strange. Thanks for the information. I didn't know about it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why it doesn't,t work I think your code is correct but I have another way to do that you can use stream provider instead of stream builder

wrap the stream provider above your material app or cupirtinoapp :

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamProvider.value(
      value: firebaseauht.inistance.onauthchange,
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: Wholescreen(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

then call the provider in the wholescreen :

```
class Wholescreen extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var provider = Provider.of<User>(context);
    if (provider!=null) {
      return AnimatedSplashScreen(
            splashIconSize: SizeConfig.blockSizeVertical * 16,
            splashTransition: SplashTransition.fadeTransition,
            nextScreen: HomeScreen(),
            splash: kLogoImage,
            duration: 800,
    } else {
      return AnimatedSplashScreen(
            splashIconSize: SizeConfig.blockSizeVertical * 16,
            splashTransition: SplashTransition.fadeTransition,
            nextScreen: LoginScreen(),
            splash: kLogoImage,
            duration: 800,
          ); 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It asks me to provide `initialData`. What should I put there?

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
  signOut() async {
    await googleSignIn.signOut();
    Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, MyRoutes.loginScreen);
  }
```

Into this:

```
  signOut() async {
    await googleSignIn.disconnect();
    Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, MyRoutes.loginScreen);
  }
```

According to the docs the [disconnect](https://pub.dev/documentation/google_sign_in/latest/google_sign_in/GoogleSignIn/disconnect.html) method is what revokes the authentication/signs the user out.